# How to replace fragment from array

Tags: java, android, arrays, android-fragments

I don't get this.. I'm trying to use transaction.replace to replace one fragment with another, using an arrayAdapter. The value in the array is a com.example.package.fragment- address. But I can't figure out how to actually replace the fragment.

If I try to use the code below with these lines:

```
FragmentTransaction transaction = getFragmentManager()
                .beginTransaction();
        transaction.replace(R.id.fragment_container, Fragment.instantiate(this, getResources().getStringArray(R.array.adressLista[position])));
        transaction.commit();
```

I get "The type of the expression must be an array type but it resolved to int". But if I use the same R.array to replace text in a TextView, like this:

```
TextView infoText = (TextView) getActivity().findViewById(R.id.fragmentTextView);
        infoText.setText(getResources().getStringArray(R.array.adressLista)[position]);
```

Then the text shown is the com.example. address. How do I replace the Fragment?

Codes:
VisaFragment (The error is on the 11th row From the Bottom):

```
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentTransaction;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.TextView;

public class VisaFragment extends Fragment {

    static final String ARG_POSITION = "position";
    int mCurrentPosition = -1;

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, 
            Bundle savedInstanceState){ 

        if (savedInstanceState != null){
            mCurrentPosition = savedInstanceState.getInt(ARG_POSITION);
        }

        return inflater.inflate(R.layout.om_sida, container, false);    
    }

    @Override
    public void onStart(){
        super.onStart();
System.out.println("VisaFragment onStart");     

        Bundle argument = getArguments();
        if (argument != null){
            visaFragmentArgument(argument.getInt(ARG_POSITION));
        }else if (mCurrentPosition != -1){
            visaFragmentArgument(mCurrentPosition);
        }
    }

    public void visaFragmentArgument(int position) {
System.out.println("VisaFragment VisaFragmentArgument");

        FragmentTransaction transaction = getFragmentManager()
                .beginTransaction();
        transaction.replace(R.id.fragment_container, Fragment.instantiate(this, getResources().getStringArray(R.array.adressLista[position])));
        transaction.commit();
        }

    @Override
    public void onSaveInstanceState(Bundle outState) {
        super.onSaveInstanceState(outState);

        outState.putInt(ARG_POSITION, mCurrentPosition);
    }
}
```

MenyFragment:

```
    import android.app.Activity;
    import android.os.Bundle;
    import android.support.v4.app.ListFragment;
    import android.view.View;
    import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
    import android.widget.ListView;

    public class MenyFragment extends ListFragment{

        onMenyKnappClickListener mCallback;
        public interface onMenyKnappClickListener {
            public void onMenyKnappVald (int position);
        }

        @Override
        public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    System.out.println("MenyFragment onCreate");
            int layout = android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1;
            setListAdapter (new ArrayAdapter<String>(getActivity(), layout, getResources().getStringArray(R.array.menyLista)));
        }

        @Override
        public void onListItemClick(ListView l, View v, int position, long id) {
    System.out.println("MenyFragment onListItemClick");     
            mCallback.onMenyKnappVald(position);
            getListView().setItemChecked(position, true);
        }

        @Override
        public void onStart() {
            super.onStart();
            System.out.println("MenyFragment onStart");
            if (getFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.fragment_container_stor) !=null){
                getListView().setChoiceMode(ListView.CHOICE_MODE_SINGLE);
                }
        }

        @Override
        public void onAttach(Activity activity) {
            super.onAttach(activity);
    System.out.println("MenyFragment onAttach");
            try {
                mCallback =(onMenyKnappClickListener) activity;
            } catch (ClassCastException e) {
                throw new ClassCastException(activity.toString() + " Måste implementera onMenyKnappClickListener");
            }
        }
}
```

MainActivity:

```
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentTransaction;

public class MainActivity extends FragmentActivity implements MenyFragment.onMenyKnappClickListener{

    @Override
    public void onCreate (Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
System.out.println("MainActivity onCreate");
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        if (findViewById(R.id.fragment_container_liten) != null){
            if (savedInstanceState != null){
                return;
            }

            MenyFragment menyFragment = new MenyFragment();
            menyFragment.setArguments(getIntent().getExtras());
            getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction()
            .add(R.id.fragment_container, menyFragment).commit();
        }
    }

    public void onMenyKnappVald (int position){
System.out.println("MainActivity onMenyKnappVald");

    VisaFragment visaFrag = (VisaFragment) getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.fragment_container);

    if (visaFrag != null) {
        visaFrag.visaFragmentArgument(position);

    }else{
        VisaFragment nyttFragment = new VisaFragment();
        Bundle argument = new Bundle ();

        argument.putInt(VisaFragment.ARG_POSITION, position);
        nyttFragment.setArguments(argument);
        FragmentTransaction transaction = getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
        transaction.replace(R.id.fragment_container, nyttFragment);
        transaction.addToBackStack(null);
        transaction.commit();
    }


    }

}
```

activity_main.XML

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:baselineAligned="false"
    android:orientation="horizontal"    
    android:background="@color/menyBGColor"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <fragment android:name="com.example.exempelfragmentsgrund.MenyFragment"
              android:id="@+id/meny_fragment"
              android:layout_weight="1"
              android:layout_width="0dp"
              android:layout_height="match_parent" />

    <fragment android:name="com.example.exempelfragmentsgrund.VisaFragment"
              android:id="@+id/fragment_container"
              android:layout_weight="3"
              android:layout_width="0dp"
              android:layout_height="match_parent" />

</LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You see that you have

```
getResources().getStringArray(R.array.adressLista[position])
```

in the first and then in TextView stuff this

```
getResources().getStringArray(R.array.adressLista)[position]
```

So you only have to move that `[position]` outside from the `getStringArray` method.

The line `getResources().getStringArray(R.array.adressLista[position])` gives you error because getStringArray takes int parameter and you are trying to use R.array.adressLista like it was an array but it's integer which refers to the array in your values.xml.

Comment: If I do that, I get: "The method instantiate(Context, String) in the type Fragment is not applicable for the arguments (VisaFragment, String)"

Comment: Try replacing `this` with `getActivity()`

Comment: So it would look like this:
`transaction.replace(R.id.fragment_container, Fragment.instantiate(getActivity(), getResources().getStringArray(R.array.adressLista)[position]));`

Comment: Aah! Thanks! That got rid of the code errors! 
However, Now It crashes, when I click the array-list, I don't know if that has anything to do with my previous issue, or if there's something wrong elsewhere: http://pastebin.com/UVBwpkWb

Answer (score 0):

```
Fragment.instantiate(this, getResources().getStringArray(R.array.adressLista[position])));
```

`getResources().getStringArray()` returns `int []` and your above snippet would return an `int`. setText has two variants so it works: `setText(int)` `setText(String)`

Comment: Ok, so that's why I still can use setText, but not transaction.replace. Since the array value is a text, i suppose this int is referring to a value id?